# Timestamp value returned with no documentation to describe what the value represents

Tags: c#, c, timestamp

Does anyone recognize what the value 1607293133099 might represent as a "timestamp"?

The return data type is defined as:

> ```
> unsigned long long timestamp;
> ```

.. with no reference point or documentation to tell me what the value represents.

The value represents an action completed "now" result; but I am unable to convert it successfully to a datetime that is today's date and time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Milliseconds since the start of the Unix epoch (1970)](https://www.epochconverter.com): Sunday, December 6, 2020, 22:18:53.099 UTC. Is it a timestamp from about 20 minutes before you asked?

Comment: This would be my conclusion as well, definitely looks to be a Unix epoch timestamp. I would probably use a DateTime property myself, which provides a method for getting an epoch timestamp and is much more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

That represents this timestamp:

```
$ t 1607293133099
Sat Feb 3 19:44:59 CET 52903 <= Europe/Madrid
Sat Feb 3 20:44:59 EET 52903 <= Europe/Helsinki
Sat Feb 3 18:44:59 UTC 52903 <= GMT
```

well, year 52903 is still a little far, but... if you truncate the last three digits,  it becomes:

```
$ t 1607293133
Sun Dec 6 23:18:53 CET 2020 <= Europe/Madrid
Mon Dec 7 00:18:53 EET 2020 <= Europe/Helsinki
Sun Dec 6 22:18:53 UTC 2020 <= GMT
```

which is far more suitable.  The number(the original you posted) represents the number of milliseconds transcurred between the date you are timestamping and the epoch of 1/1/1970 00:00:00 UTC